# what is the best way to move logic from controller to a service

Tags: laravel, design-patterns, singleton, factory-pattern, liskov-substitution-principle

my question is : **How to take my business logic out of controller and transfer it to a service ???**
I am currently using two separate controllers for Post model in Laravel. One for user-related logic and one for administrator-related logic.
pseudo code for **AdminPostController** :

```
class AdminPostController
{
    public function index(MaybyIndexRequest $request)
    {
        $something = do lines of  calculation
        return return PostResource::collection($something);
    }

    public function storeAdminPost(StorePostRequest $request)
    {
        $something = do lines of  calculation
        return return PostStoreResource::collection($something);
    }
}
```

pseudo code for **UserPostController** :

```
class UserPostController
{
    public function maybyUserindex(AnotherIndexRequest $request)
    {
        $something = do lines of  calculation
        return return UserPostResource::collection($something);
    }

    public function storeUserPost(OtherStorePostRequest $request)
    {
        $something = do lines of  calculation
        return return UserPostStoreResource::collection($something);
    }
}
```

I want to transfer the business logic of these two controllers to another class and call them with the help of, for example, a Facade like :
class AdminPostController
{
public function index(MaybyIndexRequest $request)
{
$something = PostService::($request);
return return PostResource::collection($something);
}

```
    public function storeUserPost(StorePostRequest $request)
    {
        $something = PostService::Store($request);
        return return PostStoreResource::collection($something);
    }
}
```

**But I do not know with what design patterns I should do this. Or what I'm looking for is not a good way to get the code out of the controller !!!**
*The way to solve this problem came to my mind :*
factory pattern : a class that has two methods called user() and admin().

```
class PostFactory
{
    public function AdminCommands()
    {
        return new AdminPostCommands(); // a class that contains admin 
    }

    public function UserCommands()
    {
        return new UserPostCommands(); // a class that contains user related logics

    }
}
```

That the user method returns an instance of UserPostCommands class (including the user's logic) and the AdminCommands class method (contains the's post logic) .... or :

```
    class PostFactory
    {
            public function Factory(User $user)
        {
            if ($user->isAdmin){
                 return new AdminPostCommands(); // a class that contains admin 
            }else{
                 return new UserPostCommands(); // a class that contains user related logics
            }
    
    }
```

a class that it takes an instance of the **authorized user** to decide whether the **AdminPostCommands** OR **UserPostCommands** class should be Returned. each of these two classes(*AdminPostCommands* or *UserPostCommands* ) has different methods. For example, the user may not be able to delete a post . Of course, user-related methods will only be used in the user controller and vice versa.

Comment: If you're looking to extract some logic from your controller because it is doing too much, I would consider looking at [`events`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/events) for what you have described.

Comment: It might be also be helpful if you show what logic will be required in these service classes, if you can.

Comment: I think I need to create two completely separate services, one for administrators and the other for users. I think I have to look at the fact that two separate services control a common model. The classes that make up these two services are not of the same type ("not" is a) and therefore do not have common methods. This seems to be related to the interface segregation !

Answer (score 0):

Look's like you are deviating from the standard conventions of Laravel.

Perhaps, it might be worthwhile spending some time learning about them. For example, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers on how to structure controllers.

`storeUserPost` should simply be `store`, you are in the UserPost controller, so it's implied that what you are storing will be a UserPost. Any logic required can be moved to an event or a service/utility class.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/events#introduction

A controller shouldn't, usually, be doing more than querying/storing/updating the model with the new data or calling other classes that perform logic and returning a view or redirect, generally speaking.

Comment: I don't completely agree with `All a controller should be doing is querying/storing/updating the model with the new data or calling other classes that perform logic and returning a view or redirect`, using a repository or service can allow code reusage so it is a good idea to querying/storing/updating to be done in that, you can't call a controller instance but you can call a repository or service instance between different parts of project